# is distinct an expensive query in django?

Tags: django, many-to-many, distinct

I have three models: Product, Category and Place.
Product has ManyToMany relation with Category and Place.
I need to get a list of categories with at least on product matching a specific place.
For example I might need to get all the categories that has at least one product from Boston.

I have 100 categories, 500 places and 100,000 products.

In sqlite with 10K products the query takes ~ a second.
In production I'll use postgresql.

I'm using:

```
categories = Category.objects.distinct().filter(product__place__name="Boston")
```

Is this query going to be expensive?
Is there a better way to do this?

This is the result of connection.queries

```
{'time': '0.929', 'sql': u'SELECT DISTINCT "catalog_category"."id", "catalog_category"."name" FROM "catalog_category" INNER JOIN "catalog_product_categories" ON ("catalog_category"."id" = "catalog_product_categories"."category_id") INNER JOIN "catalog_product" ON ("catalog_product_categories"."product_id" = "catalog_product"."id") INNER JOIN "catalog_product_places" ON ("catalog_product"."id" = "catalog_product_places"."product_id") INNER JOIN "catalog_place" ON ("catalog_product_places"."car_id" = "catalog_car"."id") WHERE "catalog_place"."name" = Boston  ORDER BY "catalog_category"."name" ASC'}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not just a Django issue; DISTINCT is slow on most SQL implementations because it's a relatively hard operation. [Here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-02/msg00220.php) is a good discussion of why it's slow in Postgres specifically.

One way to handle this would be to use Django's excellent [caching mechanism](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) on this query, assuming that the results don't change often and minor staleness isn't a problem. Another approach would be to keep a separate list of just the distinct categories, perhaps in another table.

Comment: The link to Django's caching mechanism is broken, but only adding one character is too small an edit apparently. It's only missing a trailing 'e' It should be: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache

Answer (score -2):

Although Chase is right that DISTINCT is generally a slow operation, in this case it is also completely pointless. As you can see from the generated SQL, the DISTINCT is being done on the combination of ID and name - which will never be duplicated anyway. So there is no need for the `distinct()` call in this query.

Generally, Django does not return duplicate results from a simple filter. The main time when `distinct()` is useful is when you are accessing a related queryset via a ManyToMany or ForeignKey relationship, where multiple items might be related to the same instance, and distinct will remove the duplicates.

Comment: I do get duplicate results in this case if I don't use distinct() and I do have ManyToMany relationship. Unless I'm missing something and doing something wrong?