# django - how to do this with kwargs

Tags: python, django, keyword-argument

I am wondering when I touch db when doing queries. more precisely, when is the query performed:

i have this kwargs dic:

```
kwargs = {'name__startswith':'somename','color__iexact':'somecolor'}
```

but only for `name__startswith` query, i need to `distinct()`. and not for `color__iexact`.

I thought, i would set for `name__startswith` the `distinct()` in loop like this:

```
for q in kwargs: 
  if q == 'name__startswith':
    Thing.objects.filter(name__startswith=somename).distinct('id')
```

and then query for all dynamically:

```
allthings = Thing.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

but this is somehow wrong, i seem to be doing two different things here..

how can i do these two queries dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django querysets are [lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), so the actual queries aren't [evaluated until you use the data.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

```
allthings = Thing.objects.filter(**kwargs)

if 'name__startswith' in kwargs:
  allthings = allthings.distinct('id')
```

No queries should be preformed above unitl you actually use the data. This is great for filtering queries as you wish to do

---

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy):

QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated. Take a look at this example:

```
>>> q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
>>> q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
>>> q = q.exclude(body_text__icontains="food")
>>> print(q)
```

Though this looks like three database hits, in fact it hits the database only once, at the last line (print(q)). In general, the results of a QuerySet aren’t fetched from the database until you “ask” for them. When you do, the QuerySet is evaluated by accessing the database. For more details on exactly when evaluation takes place, see When QuerySets are evaluated.

Comment: thanks man, i decided to ``distinct`` on all queries, which doesnot damage anything. thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Using `distinct` can significantly slower your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977739/is-distinct-an-expensive-query-in-django

Answer (score 1):

You can use [models.Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)  to create dynamic queries in django.

```
query = models.Q(name__startswith=somename)

query &= models.Q('color__iexact':'somecolor')

all_things = Thing.objects.filter(query).distinct('name')
```

Also read
[Constructing Django filter queries dynamically with args and kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510057/constructing-django-filter-queries-dynamically-with-args-and-kwargs?rq=1)

Comment: but you are ``distinct`` ing also for `color__iexact`, i need also for `name__startswith`

Comment: No, the distinct takes a column name and you can just provide the column you want to have a distinct on. Updated my answer to do distinct by name

Comment: oh okay, great. thank you so much. I didnot know anything about ``Q``. you gave me new approach. thanks in tons

Comment: And to be a bit more explicit, it will not do distinct on `color`, if you want distinct combinations of color and name you can do `distinct('name', 'color')`